# Many to many relation. ORM Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

```
class Toy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    desc = models.TextField()

class Box(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    proprietor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='User_Box')
    toys = models.ManyToManyField(Toy, blank=True)
```

How to create a view that add Toy to Box?

```
def add_this_toy_to_box(request, toy_id):
```

Comment: what do you want the view to do? what have you tried?

Comment: I try add object from Toy model to the Box model. For example: Toy - name = "Ponny", desc = "pink ponny". I want add this data to Box model: Box - name = "Box1", proprietor = "user3", toys="Ponny" and maybe other toys.

Comment: can the toy belong to other boxes as well or just to one box at a time?

Comment: The Toy can belong to other boxes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Django's [`RelatedManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/):

> A “related manager” is a manager used in a one-to-many or many-to-many related context. This happens in two cases:
>
> The “other side” of a ForeignKey relation. That is:

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    ...

class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)
```

> In the above example, the methods below will be available on the manager `reporter.article_set`.
>
> Both sides of a ManyToManyField relation:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    ...

class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

> In this example, the methods below will be available both on `topping.pizza_set` and on `pizza.toppings`.

These related managers have some extra methods:

1. To create a new object, saves it and puts it in the related object set. Returns the newly created object:
       create(**kwargs)

   ```
   >>> b = Toy.objects.get(id=1)
   >>> e = b.box_set.create(
   ...     name='Hi',
   ... )

   # No need to call e.save() at this point -- it's already been saved.

   # OR:

   >>> b = Toy.objects.get(id=1)
   >>> e = Box(
   ...     toy=b,
   ...     name='Hi',
   ... )
   >>> e.save(force_insert=True)
   ```
2. To add model objects to the related object set:

   ```
   add(obj1[, obj2, ...])
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   >>> t = Toy.objects.get(id=1)
   >>> b = Box.objects.get(id=234)
   >>> t.box_set.add(b) # Associates Box b with Toy t.
   ```
3. To removes the specified model objects from the related object set:

   ```
   remove(obj1[, obj2, ...])

   >>> b = Toy.objects.get(id=1)
   >>> e = Box.objects.get(id=234)
   >>> b.box_set.remove(e) # Disassociates Entry e from Blog b.
   ```

   > In order to prevent database inconsistency, this method only exists on ForeignKey objects where null=True. If the related field can't be set to None (NULL), then an object can't be removed from a relation without being added to another. In the above example, removing e from b.entry_set() is equivalent to doing e.blog = None, and because the blog ForeignKey doesn't have null=True, this is invalid.
4. Removes all objects from the related object set:
       clear()

   ```
   >>> b = Toy.objects.get(id=1)
   >>> b.box_set.clear()
   ```

   > Note this doesn't delete the related objects -- it just disassociates them.
   >   Just like remove(), clear() is only available on ForeignKeys where null=True.

---

Reference: [Relevant Django doc on handling related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/)

Answer (score 2):

Django automatically creates reverse relations on ManyToManyFields, so you can do:

```
toy = Toy.objects.get(id=toy_id)
toy.box_set.add(box)
```